# NoSuchSessionException in selenium on git

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci

I have selenium script running on Firefox browser. This script execute well on local system but when we push the code on GIT and execute pipeline then it break after executing some steps by throwing below exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', ip: '1XXXXXX', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: 'XXXXX-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 75.0,   javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200403170909,  moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 64, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofilerzeT93, moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX,   platformVersion: 00000aws, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 7061f603-50d8-48c7-bfc0-e75...}
Session ID: 7061f603-50d8-48c7-bfc0-e7540fd5c115
```

YML File have this code to get Firefox driver:

```
services:
    - selenium/standalone-Firefox
```

Same thing happens with chrome. What i observed when system did not find the element, and went to take the  screen shot  script throws this error. And this is intermittent, some time works well.

Please help if have face such type of issue.

Comment: Is this something that's worked in the past and is now breaking, or is this a new build pipeline? If the latter, are you installing Firefox/Chrome as well? In my CI YML file I have a line for downloading the driver but another line for downloading the actual browser too. Could this be your issue?

Comment: Yes, It worked till first week of Apr. and now it start breaking. and I m using selenium/standalone-Firefox  or selenium/standalone-chrome.

Comment: . and this is a headless mode.

Comment: @ewhiting Any idea?

Comment: tell me if this helps [install browsers and webdrivers in TravisCI](https://dev.to/erikwhiting88/install-browsers-and-webdrivers-in-travisci-n76) if you scroll to the bottom, you will see the whole .yml file and how I get the browsers and relevant web drivers